# How to use multiple columns as inputs for apply function in R

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

I have the following dataframe,

```
df = data.frame("title1" = c("This is the Title", "This is a longer Title"), 
                "title2" = c("This is the Title", "This is an even longer Title"), 
                "url" = c("google.com","google.com"),
                "idx" = c(1,2),
                "insertion" = c("word1","word2")
                )
```

which looks like this:

[image]

What I would like to achieve is that for each row the word from column `insertion` gets inserted into the string in column `title1` at the position of column `idx`. Here is my approach:

```
df$title1 <- sapply(df$title1, function(x) unlist(strsplit(x, " ")))
df$title1 <- sapply(df$title1, function(x) append(x, df$insertion, after = df$idx))
df$title1 <- sapply(df$title1, function(x) paste(x, collapse = ' '))
```

This however returns a warning and only uses row 1 of columns `idx` and `insertion` for each calculation of column `title1`. How do I get the desired behaviour?

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for hinting me in the right direction. Your code does not work dynamically (when idx column is changed). I guess it is due to this part: paste('\\1\\2', y). I posted the solution which works best for me below.

Comment: df = data.frame("title1" = c("This is the Title", "This is a longer Title"), 
                "title2" = c("This is the Title", "This is an even longer Title"), 
                "url" = c("google.com","google.com"),
                "idx" = c(2,3),
                "insertion" = c("word1","word2")
)

Comment: It cuts out the first word in the second row.

Comment: Thank you for providing an additional example. The regex needed a slight improvement.

Comment: Looks good now, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A base R regex solution -

```
mapply(function(x, y, z) 
  sub(sprintf('((?:\\w+\\s){%d})(\\w+)', x), paste('\\1\\2', y), z), 
  df$idx - 1, df$insertion, df$title1)

#[1] "This word1 is the Title"      "This is word2 a longer Title"
```

We extract the `idx` - 1th word from each string and paste it with `insertion` word.

Answer (score 0):

A solution which works dynamically:

```
mapply(function(x, y, z)
  paste(append(unlist(strsplit(z, " ")), y, after = x), collapse = " "),
  df$idx, df$url , df$title1)
```

Thank you Ronak Shah for the hint!